# How to apply different groups of substitution rules to a list of strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a function that is `applyRules(char, rules)`.
It should take

- A single character.
- A set of rules as a list.

The format of the rules list should be a set of strings in the following format:

character1: substitution, character2: substitution, etc.

I want to loop through the rules list, and parse the strings into symbol and substitutions (by using `split()` function maybe)?

This is what I have so far:

```
def applyRules(char, rules):
    newstr = ""
    for x in char:
        newstr += s[0].replace('#') + s[1].replace('*')
    return newstr
```

Am I understanding the format right?

Comment: In your code where did the variable `s` come from. Also, why aren't you using the `rules` parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understood I think this is what you want:

```
def applyRules(char, rules):
    for rule_list in (rule.split(':') for rule in rules):
        char = char.replace(rule_list[0], rule_list[1])
    return char
```

Ex: `print(applyRules('b', ['b:c', 'c:p']))` outputs `'p'`

Comment: What should I do to ask user to input rules?

`rules = input("Put your rules")`
Would this be fine?

Comment: You should give them an example on how the rules are structured.

Comment: `['b:c', 'c:p']` would be the example of rules? Do they have to put all those or only 'b:c', 'c:p' ? or 'b:c, c:p'?

Comment: I think it would be best if they entered rules one at a time using a loop and put each rule into the `rules` list

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fairly simple way to do it using a dictionary to hold the substitution rules:

```
rules = {
    '#': 'No. ',
    '*': 'one or more',
    # etc
}

def applyRules(text, rules):
    for rule in rules:
        text = text.replace(rule, rules[rule])
    return text

test = """
  #1 - Never tell a lie.
  #2 - There can be * of them.
"""

print(applyRules(test, rules))
```

Output:

```
  No. 1 - Never tell a lie.
  No. 2 - There can be one or more of them.
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but it seems like your code and description are different. If char is a single character, then how are you going to iterate over it? Is this what you're looking for?

```
def apply_rules(char, rules_list):
    for old, new in map(lambda x: x.split(':'), rules_list):
        char = char.replace(old, new)
    return char
```